# ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedState

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appcompat, android-savedstate

I am seeing the following error in my Android crash reports:

```
android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedState
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3974)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:139)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1299)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedState
   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2154)
   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2104)
   at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2020)
   at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2382)
   at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1742)
   at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2077)
   at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2321)
   at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
   at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1273)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1744)
   at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1017)
   at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:989)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1138)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3974)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:139)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1299)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

It appears to happen intermittently when resuming an activity. I do not directly access the SavedState class in any code.

**EDIT:** 
Layout Xml for my activity is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
....
```

And toolbar XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

And in my Activity's onCreate I do

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_txn);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    mResources = getResources();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        long id = savedInstanceState.getLong(STA_TXN_ID);
        ...
    } else {
        ... read fresh
    }

    mDateTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ASTVDate);
    mDayTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ASTVDay);
    mCatName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ASTVCatName);
    mMonthTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ASTVMonth);
    ....

    Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(txn.getTxnDate());
    mDateTV.setText("" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    mDayTV.setText(c.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US));
    mMonthTV.setText(c.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US));
}
```

And I have been using appcompat-v7:22.1.1 and yes I get these errors after proguard.

Comment: Post your xml and java code pls

Comment: Added my relevant test code in edited quetion

Comment: Pls add the full java code, the problem is there according to log file

Comment: What version of appcompat-v7 are you using ?

Comment: Is this after proguard?

Comment: Added the appcompat version and yes this is port proguard

Comment: Please add your comments to this bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175140

Comment: I do not use proguard, but have this issue. Also I use toolbar with `SupportMapFragment` and `appcompat-v7:22.2.0`. I restore my app from background and get this error in fragment `onCreate` in `super.onCreate()` call.

Comment: I am also having this problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like following issue is exactly about it:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196430

Comment: As a summary of the above Google Code issue, the problem seems to happen only on older devices (i.e. 2.3.7 and lower). Personally I ran into this issue with a device running API 10 (2.3.7). It looks like it will not be fixed any time soon, if ever, for older devices, but has been fixed on newer devices, so nothing users (and developers) can do short of getting a newer device.

Comment: This is not only an older device problem.  Its a restore state problem. If you take a newer phone, go into debug settings and force activities to always be killed you will see this happen.  Which means if your newer phone is running low on memory and needs to kill off activities and then restore them from state it will fail.  Google needs to fix this!

Answer (score 1):

According to AAverin's source, [Google Issue 196430](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196430), build tools version 24 includes a fix.

*E.G. change the build tools version in build.gradle:*

```
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
```

*Alternatively, prevent crashes by catching (in my particular case):*

```
try {
    // Temporary fix for crash issue
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: also in my case, it is crashing in `mapview.oncreate(savedInstanceState)` which is called in my fragment's `onViewCreated()` which is in a viewpager

Comment: And build tools 25 breaks it again!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when I was passing 2 parable objects 
one of type A and other of type B containing type A object. I passed them in parceable array and my problem got resolved.

Comment: Activity 1

Intent intent = new Intent(this, R1.class);
Parcelable pa[] = null;<br/>
pa = new Parcelable[3];
pa[0] = obj1;
pa[1] = obj2;
pa[2] = obj3;

intent.putExtra(“ArrayObj”, pa);


Activity 2

Parcelable ArrayObj[] = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(“ArrayObj”);
  s1 = (T1)ArrayObj[0];
  s2 = (T2)ArrayObj[1];;